# TypeError: app.route is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm new on React/Express/Node world and I'm studying an app that allows the user to create a login and an API that create tasks.

I'm trying to put both together in the same application, but when I call a GET for the list of tasks, I got this error:

```
TypeError: app.route is not a function
    at module.exports (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/server/routes/schedule.js:6:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at initialize (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/slauriano/workspace/authentication-in-react-apps/part-2-json-web-token/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

This is the code snippet of the todoList.js in route folder:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
var todoList = require('../controllers/todoListController');

// todoList Routes
app.route('/tasks')
    .get(todoList.list_all_tasks)
    .post(todoList.create_a_task);


app.route('/tasks/:taskId')
    .get(todoList.read_a_task)
    .put(todoList.update_a_task)
    .delete(todoList.delete_a_task);
};
```

That is anything else I've missed? That is the snippet of the part of Authentication app that is working fine in the same route folder:

```
const express = require('express');


const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "You're authorized to see this secret message."
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I'll appreciate any help for this ;)

That's my repository https://github.com/slaurianodev/agenda-app. Feel free to clone and help with this issue.

Tks

Sergio

Comment: the error is pretty clear. you export a function from `scheduleRoutes` but then you don't pass `app` to it

Comment: How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the todoList.js with the app parameter? What I usually do is this when using another file as routing file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('<path to file>/todoList.js');
routes(app);
```

This way you're passing the app to the file that handles routing. Hope this helps.